# Import JSON file into MongoDB

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, json.net

I have a MongoDB instance on a Virtual Machine and I can connect using Compass.  I have manually uploaded a JSON file using command line on that virtual machine without issue.  The import creates two documents and works as expected using the command line:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db Historian_ManyDocs --collection TagValues --file historianData1.json
```

The json has the following format in the historianData1.json file:

```
[
    {
      "tagname": "99CalcTrigger",
      "engunits": "",
      "value": "2",
      "quality": "Good NonSpecific",
      "timestamp": "2018-12-13T10:45:05Z"
    },
    {
      "tagname": "Blank",
      "engunits": "",
      "value": "0",
      "quality": "Good NonSpecific",
      "timestamp": "2018-12-13T10:45:00Z"
    }
]
```

I want to automate this process somewhat and I have been playing with c# to do this using the following code:

```
    string line;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\historianData1.json")){
        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }


    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://mongoserverIP:27017");
    var database = client.GetDatabase("Historian_ManyDocs");
    dynamic array = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(line);
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(item);
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("TagValues");
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
    }
```

This errors with the following error on the `var document` line with the following error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize(MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument,
>   System.Action)'
>   has some invalid arguments'

Can anyone offer some suggestions please as I have been on this for 4 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert a [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object) class into MonngoDB, so please create it like this:

```
public class POCOData
{
  public string tagname;
  public string engunits;
  public string value;
  public string quality;
  public TimeOffset timestamp;
}
```

after you can use it in `Deserialize`:

```
foreach (var item in array)
{
    var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<POCOData>(item);
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("TagValues");
    await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
}
```